# how to feed 5D tensor into LSTM?

Tags: python, keras, reshape, lstm, conv-neural-network

I have video data with input shape of the 3D CNN network as (150, 80, 80, 16, 3).

I got the output of conv layer with shape (150, 7, 7, 2, 512) that indicates to:

150 No. of sequences

7,7 height and width

2 temporal dimension

512 feature maps

I want to feed this into LSTM, so I reshaped the output data into:

```
model.add(Reshape((1, 7*7*2*512)))
model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequence=true))
```

it works with LSTM but I am not sure if this is correct or not (should I put the time-space = 16 and change the feature number to 3136, based on the temporal dimension that we chose in the beginning). I know that LSTM should get a data with the shape (sequences, time-space, features).

Please if you have any suggestion I will be happy for that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are really close but you are missing a crucial step to organise the *timesteps* or the temporal dimension. What you are after is `(150, 2, 7*7*512)` which indicates 150 samples, 2 timesteps and flattened features. So you can first permute then reshape:

```
model.add(Permute((3, 1, 2, 4)) # (samples, 2, 7, 7, 512)
model.add(Reshape((2, 7*7*512)) # (samples, 2, 7*7*512)
```

Now the LSTM will process 2 timesteps of flattened image features.

Note that this is actually very large feature space for every timestep, you might want to reduce the feature set by pooling operations or other CNN layers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did what you said I decreased the feature maps to 128 using 3D conv and pooling layers. The thing is the accuracy still going down when I use LSTM after these layers, while it goes up when I remove the LSTM layer. Any justification for that please?

Comment: There is no correlation between the timesteps that an LSTM can learn to improve the result.

Comment: Do you mean that I should increase the timesteps? if so, should I get back to previous layer to get more temporal dimension or just reshape the current shape into (2*7, 7*512)? Thank you

Comment: I don't know, you could increase and test see what happens. In that case you need to get more temporal dimension yes.