# How to fed 5D tensor of 3dcnn to LSTM?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, computer-vision, lstm

I am working in action recognition field, where I have to use 3dcnn and Lstm.
My input size for 3DCNN is [1,3,16,112,112]. I need to fed the output from 3dcnn layer to lstm.
I am getting problem implementing the Model.

Below is my network architecture for 3dcnn. I need to add Lstm layer after pool5.

Please,I will be really grateful for any guidance and help.
Thank You.^^

```
def __init__(self):
    super(C3D, self).__init__()

    self.conv1 = nn.Conv3d(3, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), padding=(1, 1, 1))
    self.pool1 = nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size=(1, 2, 2), stride=(1, 2, 2))

    self.conv2 = nn.Conv3d(64, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), padding=(1, 1, 1))
    self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size=(2, 2, 2), stride=(2, 2, 2))

    self.conv3a = nn.Conv3d(128, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), padding=(1, 1, 1))
    self.conv3b = nn.Conv3d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), padding=(1, 1, 1))
    self.pool3 = nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size=(2, 2, 2), stride=(2, 2, 2))

    self.conv4a = nn.Conv3d(256, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), padding=(1, 1, 1))
    self.conv4b = nn.Conv3d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), padding=(1, 1, 1))
    self.pool4 = nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size=(2, 2, 2), stride=(2, 2, 2))

    self.conv5a = nn.Conv3d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), padding=(1, 1, 1))
    self.conv5b = nn.Conv3d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), padding=(1, 1, 1))
    self.pool5 = nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size=(2, 2, 2), stride=(2, 2, 2), padding=(0, 1, 1))

    self.relu = nn.ReLU()
```

Answer (score 0):

Key point is to make sure to use the flattened image feature dimension as the LSTM input feature dimension.

```
def __init__(self):
    ...
    self.lstm = nn.LSTM(H*W*512, hidden_size, batch_first=True)
    ...
def forward(self):
    ...
    # 3dcnn_out.shape = (batch_size, timesteps, H, W, 512)
    3dcnn_out.reshape(batch_size, timesteps, H*W*512)
    out, (h, c) = self.lstm(3dcnn_out)
    ...
```

(Possible duplicate of [how to feed 5D tensor into LSTM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50689494/how-to-feed-5d-tensor-into-lstm))